# Function doesn't end at return

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having an odd issue.
I have this function to check if a certain entry exists in `sqflite`, it is supposed to return true if it does, false if not. 
But for some reason the function doesn't end when it should return true. instead it always runs through the end of the function and returns false.

The Console output is:

1. exists (should return true here),
2. {id: 1, messageId: 6, wasViewed: 0} (the result output)
3. end of function

And then it returns false.

```
  Future<bool> isMessageViewContained(int id) async {
    Database db = await this.database;

    await db.query(messagesViewTable, where: 'messageId = $id').then((res) {
      if (res.isEmpty) {
        print("doesnt exists");
        return false;
      }
      print("exists");
      print(res);
      return true;
    }).catchError((error) {
      print("doesnt exist");
      return false;
    });
    print("end of function");
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because it is executed in following order:

1. Start
2. AWAIT FOR NEXT STEPS (CALLBACKS) TO FINISH (entering async context)
3. execute db.query
4. When db.query finishes, do print("exists") and return true - in this step, not function
5. OK STEPS FINISHED, lets proceed (exiting async context)
6. print("end of function")
7. return false

So because of async context, you execute required code as a callback to async function that the main flow waits to finish - and proceeds afterwards.

in short it is like

```
 Database db = this.database;
 queryDb(someCriteria); // result is ignored
 print("end of function");
 return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `isMessageViewContained` function itself never returns true.  It invokes a `Future.then` callback, and *that callback* returns true. `isMessageViewContained` never does anything with the callback's return value.

You can fix this by changing `await db.query(...).then(...);` to `return await db.query(...).then(...);`.  Even clearer would be to just use `await` without the `.then()` and `.catchError()` callbacks:

```dart
    Future<bool> isMessageViewContained(int id) async {
    Database db = await this.database;

    try {
      var res = await db.query(messagesViewTable, where: 'messageId = $id');
      if (res.isEmpty) {
        print("doesnt exists");
        return false;
      }
      print("exists");
      print(res);
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      print("doesnt exist");
      return false;
    }
    print("end of function");
    return false;
  }
```